# specify NodeJS interpreter

Tags: node.js, interpreter

I am currently executing a nodeJS program like that:

```
$> nodejs server.js
```

Is it possible to specify the interpreter inside the file, something like:

`#!/usr/bin/nodejs`

I want to execute my program with the following command:

```
$> server.js
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, simply do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nodejs
```

And do not forget to add the executable flag to your script.

```
chmod u+x server.js
```

Comment: I already tried that solution but I have this error: ": No such file or directory"

Comment: Please retry with `nodejs` instead of `node`